# function that is/is not a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M = \{X,Y,Z,F\}$. Give examples of the following:

a) A function $d:M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$ that is a metric on M

b) A function $d:M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies only $d(x,x)=0$ and $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ criteria, but not a metric on $M$

.

I know the definition of $M \times M$. I do not know what does it mean to give a "function" that is a metric for a), and also not a metric in b). Any help?

Comment: What is each of $X$, $Y$, $Z$, and $F$? Arbitrary symbols?

Comment: A function $f\colon M\times M\to\mathbb{R}$ corresponds precisely to a choice of real numbers $d(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all the 16 pairs $(a,b)\in M\times M$. In other words: you have to specify what $f(X,X)$, $f(X,Y)$, $f(X,Z)$, $f(X,F)$, $F(Y,X)$, ..., $f(F,F)$ is (e.g. by writing down a $4\times 4$ table).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $X, Y, Z, F$ are just arbitrary elements.

a) Define $d:M\times M\to \Bbb R$ as 
$$d(a, b) = \begin{cases}0&a = b\\1& a\neq b\end{cases}$$

b) Define $d:M\times M\to \Bbb R$ as $d(x, y) = 0$ for all $x, y \in M$.

Comment: for $a$ shouldn't be the opposite. i.e. $0$ when $a=b$?

Comment: That is correct, fixed it.